# Vue Event listener priority in directive and component

Tags: vue.js

There are lot of operation like `delete` should be confirmed again by user before they can be executed, I am tired to repeat the confirm job every time, so I tried to implement that by vue  directive.

Something like that:

```
Vue.directive("confirm", {
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
        el._listener = function (e) {
            if(confirm(binding.value)){
                //do nothing,
            }else{
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();  // stop other events in this element
            }

        }
        el.addEventListener("click", el._listener)
    },
    unbind(el, binding, vnode) {
        el._listener && el.removeEventListener("click", el._listener) && (el._listener = null)
    }
});
```

//component

```
<button v-confirm @click="delete()">Delete</button>
```

However, it does not work. And I found that when the `confirm()` is called, the event listener bound by the `@click` in the component has been called yet.

Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Get the click function on the component when the `bind` hook function in the custom directive is executed

```js
Vue.directive("confirm", {
  bind(el, binding, vnode) {
    let handleFunction = binding.value

    el._listener = function(e) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure.....")) {
        //do nothing,
        alert("I'm sure")
        handleFunction && handleFunction()
      } else {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // stop other events in this element
        alert("Cancel")
      }
    }
    el.addEventListener("click", el._listener)
  },
  unbind(el, binding, vnode) {
    el._listener && el.removeEventListener("click", el._listener) && (el._listener = null)
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    deleteHandle() {
      console.log('delete')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-confirm:click="deleteHandle">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I may pass the confirm message through the `binding.value`

Comment: Of course, you can do this like `handleFunction(yesOrNo)`